# Перекрытие элементов SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Проблема в перекрытии элементов. Пробовал решить проблему так:

```
<feComponentTransfer>
         <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" /> 
</feComponentTransfer>
```

И с помощью crisp edges, но ничего не помогло. У темного круга выделяются границы.

[image: Пример проблемы]

```html
<svg witdh="140px" height="140px" viewBox="0 0 140 140">
<g  shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
  <circle  r="67" cx="70" cy="70" fill="transparent" stroke="#283C54" stroke-width="4"
  ></circle>
  <circle r="67" cx="70" cy="70" fill="transparent" stroke="#C78FF9" stroke-width="4" 
    stroke-dasharray="400 20" stroke-dashoffset="0"
  ></circle>
</g>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8keL4ym/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю для решения воспользоваться обратным dasharray

```html
<svg witdh="150px" height="150px" viewBox="-75 -75 150 150">
  <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="25px" dominant-baseline="middle">before</text>
  <g fill="none" stroke-width="14" >
    <circle r="67" stroke="#283C54"/>
    <circle r="67" stroke="#C78FF9" stroke-dasharray="400 20" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
  </g> 
</svg>

<svg witdh="150px" height="150px" viewBox="-75 -75 150 150">
  <text text-anchor="middle" font-size="25px" dominant-baseline="middle">after</text>
  <g fill="none" stroke-width="14" >
    <circle r="67" stroke="#283C54" stroke-dasharray="20 400" stroke-dashoffset="20"/>
    <circle r="67" stroke="#C78FF9" stroke-dasharray="400 20" stroke-dashoffset="0"/>
  </g> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Помогло, однако интересно в чем физика?

Comment: @я так понимаю что это результат antialiasing, еще помогает сделать толщину верхнего круга на 0.5 больше, только что проверил